# Trying to catch received SMS in Android Studio on a real device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sms

I am trying to implement an smsListner. I created my manifest with the receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".smsListner" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I add the permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

And I implement a class that extends the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class smsListner extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Toast.makeText(context, "Ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){


        }
    }
```

Now I just launch Android Studio, and send a real SMS to my device (not an emulator), but the BroadcastReceiver, onReceive method never fired.

Is it possible to debug / develop receiver SMS on a real device?

Comment: 1) Do you have the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission listed in the manifest, outside of the `<application>` tags? 2) If you're running on Marshmallow with a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or above, are you handling the runtime permission correctly? 3) If you're running on a version prior to KitKat, are you sure another app isn't intercepting and aborting the broadcast? 4) Are you sure the `name` attribute on the `<receiver>` is pointing to the right class, in the right place? 5) Are you launching an `Activity` in your app at least once after installation to bring it out of the _stopped_ state?

Comment: Hi Mike, 1) I try both, inside the application and outside the application. 2) I am not sure on the answer. I am running 6.0.1 (Marshmallow) version. I am targetting the 23 version. 3) How i can determine if another apps intercept the broadcast? 4) I am sure that the name of my receiver is good, and pointing in the rightClass (I also but the full Namespace in the name. 5) I have my main activity are running

Comment: The permissions go outside of the `<application>` tags. Also, since you're running on Marshmallow, with a `targetSdkVersion` of 23, you'd need to request the permissions at runtime, as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it). For testing purposes, you could temporarily drop the `targetSdkVersion` to <23.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but doens't work ... :-((( maybe something wrong in my code ...

Comment: Ok ... it's now working !!! Thanks

Comment: Cool. I'll just vote this as a duplicate of that post, so you can close out your question. (You might need to refresh the page.) Glad you got it working. Cheers!